# I'm looking for a book about children who go to live in the woods

Tags: identification-request

I remember reading a beautifully illustrated book about some children going to live in the woods, when I was younger. The basic plot is that a few boys decide to go live in the woods, and it goes so well, that all of the other kids in the area join them. Kids end up living in tree-houses and underground burroughs, etc... Until the parents beg them all to come home.

My guess is that it was written between the 1940's to 1960's.